# I keep getting this error when I try input phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I keep getting this error in my command line on phpStorm when I try use phpunit. Can someone explain this to me? I'm new to phpunit.

> > C:\xampp\php\phpunit.bat
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::doRun(),
>   called in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 176 and
>   defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\php_unit_testing\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php
>   on line 148
>
> PHPUnit 5.3-dev by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Fatal error: Class 'controllers\core\web\Pages' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\php_unit_testing\tests\app\controllers\core\web\PagesTest.php
>   on line 6
>
> Process finished with exit code 255 at 22:23:20. Execution time: 186
>   ms.

Here is a my code from my xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<phpunit bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php"
     color="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     stopOnFailures="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
    >
<testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Tutorial Unit Tests">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And this is the code from pages.php:

```
<?php


 namespace controllers\core\web;

 class Pages{
 public function rendor(){
    return 'Hello World';
 }

 public function return_true(){
    return true;
 }
 public function return_array(){
    return array('Hello', 'world', 'This', 'is', 'an', 'array');
 }
 }
 ?>
```

And this is the code from PagesTest.php:

```
<?php
class PagesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{ 
public function testRenderReturnsHelloWorld(){ 

    $pages = new \controllers\core\web\Pages();

    $expected = 'Hello Word'; 

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $pages->rendor());

}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're loading in the library. Typically you have to create an alternate `autoload.php` file and include that in the phpunit bootsrap value. So it would be something like this:

`<phpunit bootstrap="./autoload.php" ...`

```
  #./auotload.php
  $loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  $loader.add('directory_of_code', 'path/to/that/directory');

  return $loader;
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? What would you write inside $loader->add(). What do you mean by directory of code?

Comment: from your namespaceing up above I think it might be something like `$loader.add('controller', 'src/');`

Comment: The composer documentation is kind of junk, but they make the loader you're trying to [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) with;

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found a solution to the missing class. I add `require_once 'app/controllers/core/web/pages.php';` to require the page where I had the class stored with the namespace. This worked for me and I hope it works for anyone else that comes across this. In my autoloader file that I made I have this code now

```
<?php
require_once 'app/controllers/core/web/pages.php';
$loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I never found figured out the part about

> Warning: Missing argument 3 for PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::doRun(), called in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 176 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\php_unit_testing\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 148

If anyone figures this out please let me know.